# ipad css responsive website bug

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, layout

My site http://www.speedydealer.com has a responsive layout. Unfortunately there's a bug, when displayed on the ipad vertically the menu is expanded from the start blocking part of the page.

[image]

It's not possible to collapse the menu on the ipad. I've tried changing many parts of the CSS but can't seem to get it to work. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

I do NOT want the mobile or desktop experience to change.

Comment: You're going to have to paste code here on SO, and perhaps even create a JS Fiddle while you're at it.

Comment: I tried creating one: https://jsfiddle.net/w860h23a/   but combining the css/js hasn't worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove display:block !important  from line number 446 media-queries.css

Comment: Thanks noni that seems to resolve it! It introduces a new issue where rotating hides the menu but it's not a big problem right now

Answer (score 0):

Heej did you try this?

```
#nav-wrap ul#nav {
    display: hidden;
}
```

instead of display block. on line 447

Comment: Hi Arend, thanks for replying, your suggestion hid the menu entirely in some cases leaving the user unable to navigate.